# Modify face by its string name

Tags: faces, symbols

In my config file i have the following lines to fix faces for Scala-mode:

```
(make-face-bold scala-font-lock:lazy-face)
(make-face-bold scala-font-lock:final-face)
(make-face-bold scala-font-lock:private-face)
(make-face-bold scala-font-lock:implicit-face)
(make-face-bold scala-font-lock:abstract-face)
(make-face-bold scala-font-lock:override-face)
(make-face-bold scala-font-lock:sealed-face)
```

That i would really like to simplify to this:

```
(mapc
  (lambda (kw) (make-face-bold (make-symbol (format "scala-font-lock:%s-face" kw))))
  '("final" "private" "implicit" "abstract" "override" "sealed" "lazy"))
```

But it complains with `(error "Invalid face" scala-font-lock:final-face)`. How can i make it work, i.e refer to the face using constructed string?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(intern "name")` returns the interned symbol `name`

`make-symbol` returns a new *uninterned* symbol, which is entirely distinct from the symbol with the face properties.

Refer to <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp) Creating Symbols` <kbd>RET</kbd>